# Core Image Filter returns empty image

Tags: ios, swift2, core-image, cifilter

I am trying to build a warp kernel for a CIFilter, but the image I get back is empty, e.g. it's an image of the correct size, but of only one color.

My filter looks like this:

```
class MyWarpFilter: CIFilter {
    var inputImage: CIImage?
    let kernel = CIWarpKernel(string: getKernelString("mirrorX"))

    override var outputImage: CIImage? {
        guard let inputImage = inputImage, kernel = kernel else { return nil }
        let extend = inputImage.extent
        let imageWidth = inputImage.extent.size.width
        let arguments = [imageWidth]
        return kernel.applyWithExtent(
            extend,
            roiCallback: {
                (index, rect) in
                return rect
            },
            inputImage: inputImage,
            arguments: arguments as [AnyObject])
    }
}
```

My kernel looks like this:

```
kernel vec2 mirrorX(float imageWidth) {
    vec2 input = destCoord();
    return vec2(imageWidth - input.x, input.y);
}
```

If I replace the body of the kernel with `return destCoord();` I get the original image back as expected.

The kernel is from the 2014 WWDC presentation 512: *Developing Core Image Filters for iOS* so I would expect it to work, and it looks correct to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently `input` is a reserved keyword, replacing it with:

```
kernel vec2 mirrorX(float imageWidth) {
    vec2 p = destCoord();
    return vec2(imageWidth - p.x, p.y);
}
```

works just fine!